# How do I refer to a typed text on a site in a variable

Tags: javascript

How could I take to a text that was typed on the web site by a user and put it in a variable?

I've got a to-do list and I need to take a text of a task like 'Go to shop' that is typed by a user and put it in a variable so I could create a new line with a task.
The line where it should be typed is:

```
<body>
    <div id="myDIV" class="header">
      <h2>Мой список дел</h2>
      <input type="Go to shop" id="myInput" placeholder="Name it">
      <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Добавить</span>
    </div>
```

and I should put it here (It should be done using JS) :

```
let addNote = document.getElementById('myInput')
    addNote.onclick=function(){
        
            let span = document.createElement('li');
            let txt = document.createTextNode(input.type(the text should be here))
            span.className = 'NewTask';
            span.appendChild(txt)
            mynodelist.appendChild(span)
        }
```

Or what would you advice me to read that will help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advice

Comment: Can you please add a reproducible example (even if the code doesn't work) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a click event handler in your ".addBtn" span, you will define the function to handle the appending of new to-dos.

```
const newElement = () => {
   const mynodelist = document.getElementById('{your list id}')
   let addNote = document.getElementById('myInput');
   let span = document.createElement('li');
   let txt = document.createTextNode(addNote.value)
   span.className = 'NewTask';
   span.appendChild(txt);
   mynodelist.appendChild(span);
}
```

The {your list id} is a placeholder since from your code I could not get the Id. you need to replace that with your valid id.

Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://js.do/code/527601)

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background: rgb(233, 194, 194);
            /* try type yellow */
            color: #323232;

            margin: 10;
            height: 100vh;

            display: block;
            align-items: top;
            justify-content: left;

            font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
        }

        span.insert {
            display: inline-block;
            background: white;
            border-style: solid;
            padding: 3px;
            width: 300px;
            min-width: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        function add_deal() {
            const text = document.getElementById('insert').innerHTML;
            if (text === '') {
                console.log('INSERT TEXT');
                return false;
            }
            const ul = document.getElementById("deals");
            const li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = text;
            ul.appendChild(li);
            document.getElementById('insert').innerHTML = '';
        };
    </script>

    <span class="insert" id="insert" style="" contenteditable></span>
    <input type="button" value="Добавить" onclick="add_deal()">

    <h1>Мои дела</h1>
    <ul id="deals">
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```